# How to enable missing/hidden ethernet network interface?

Tags: networking, network-manager, ethernet

I put my laptop to sleep. When I came back my ethernet network interface is just gone. No internet so I had to use wifi to post this.

`ip link show` produces
1: lo
2: wlp.. (wifi)

Ethernet is just GONE. This happens from time to time. If I reboot, ethernet is back. But the interface name (e.g., enx806d97218e00) changes at every boot. It is a PAIN that the interface name does not stay the same across boots!!!!

Is there any way to get the interface up without doing a reboot?

Comment: Is this an internal ethernet adapter, or an external USB ethernet adapter? If external, is it connected via a dock? When it's working, edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C network`.

Comment: Ah, didn't think of that. The ethernet cable is plugged into a Lenovo dock and a USB-C connects the dock to the laptop. Do you think this is source of problem? Maybe it's a driver issue with the dock?

Comment: Probably a firmware issue in the dock. Check the Lenovo web site.